# Question on feature in different languages

Tags: discussion

I have asked the following question which I think might be controversial as it demands a list (obviously, I personally *do* think that it is of interest)

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/86/which-body-parts-can-invented-speech-be-taken-from

So please weigh in whether questions like this should be
closed
discouraged
wikified
tolerated
reformulated
welcomed

Compare with the similar but different meta discussion in
[Should we allow highly open-ended questions like "do any languages have feature X"?](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-highly-open-ended-questions-like-do-any-languages-have-feature-x)

Answer (score 5):

I'm voting to close the question. The problem is not so much that questions of this type are unanswerable, as the fact that the answer is not linguistically interesting. So people pull stuff out of their ass, ears, nose, whatever -- how is this interesting to linguists? All you're getting is a list of idioms, which is not important or relevant to linguistics.

Comment: Not -terribly- important to most linguists. It does have the flavor of sociolinguistics or linguistic anthropology.